# Nextcloud (Apache/PHP-FPM) Slow Upload Speed

Tags: php, apache, nextcloud

I'm new to Linux/Apache/PHP installations.

I have a Nextcloud installation. If I upload a large file using the browser the upload speed is about 2 - 3 MB/d (HTTP/2). I have tried using HTTP 1.1 here was the upload speed about 10 MB/s. If I upload the same file using WinSCP the upload speed reaches 50 MB/s.

So there is a huge difference in the upload speed. Any idea how I Improve the upload speed from the browser?

Phpinfo as image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1njwVwY8x6TxXWp5-9yVRmxio2I766nv4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud chunk the file before sending to the server. There are some common issues on it :

- if you have an antivirus, it scans all the chunks and not the global file. It's take more time.
- if you use object storage, the chunk are saved in it before get it back to reconstruct the real file and then saved it back in the object storage. This take very long time.

And, there is the limit of ajax (to send the chuncks). Web browser can have 6 xhr openened at the same time.

You can try to change the chunck file size to increase it : https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_files/big_file_upload_configuration.html#configuring-nextcloud

Good luck

Comment: I tried changing the chuck size but it didn't seem to have any effect. I tried again only to use HTTP 1.1 the upload speed is when between 7 MB/s and 20 MB/s. Is it normal that HTTP 1.1 is much faster when uploading large files?

Comment: When you upload directly a file, it's more faster because there are no all the scripts behind. For nextcloud, a lot off script are running witch deals with the uploads them self, the verification of the chuncks and the reconstitution of the file.